# Перевод в двоичную систему счисления больших чисел

Tags: математика, c, алгоритм, c++

Доброго времени суток!
Возник вопрос: как очень большое десятичное число(количество десятичных знаков ~10^4) быстро перевести в двоичную систему счисления?
P.S. так как ни один тип такое число не уместит, то число считывается в строку, ну или на лету обрабатывать нужно
P.P.S сторонние либы использовать нельзя

Comment: Я правильно понимаю: вы умеете перевести _медленно_, и вам нужно оптимизировать алгоритм?

Comment: GMP попробуйте. Правда не знаю насколько будет быстро.

Comment: @dzhioev к сожалению, сторонние либы использовать нельзя.

Comment: ну тогда как в школу учили, дели на 2 и записывай=)

Comment: @spirit вот примерно такой костыльный способ я и реализовал.
вот только делить на 2 число, записанное в строке совсем не айс...

Comment: Алгоритмы есть, скопирую комментарий из [другого вопроса](/questions/258765/):

> Вам нужна глава 4.4 «Искусства программирования» Кнута (это второй том).

---
Почему не айс? Нормальный такой себе способ.

Comment: @miramentis: Почему долго? Вы что-то не то делаете, нечему там тормозить. Дайте код.

Comment: @miramentis, у Вас за какое время считает 10000 десятичных цифр?

Я сделал с предложениями в своем комментарии (gcc -O3) и на i5-2500 3.3 GHz получил 0.25 сек., а на Dual Core 2.7 GHz 0.9 сек.

У Вас также медленно и (если меряли) такой же разброс по архитектурам?

Comment: @avp я не совсем понимаю, как вы храните числа и как их складываете.  
логично делать сдвиг просто "передавая адреса перед реальными битами числа", но как тогда увеличивать количество разрядов на единицу в результате сложения? ведь у нас будет выход за границы массива, избежать которого можно только скопировав все наше число с отступом от границы массива. а от memove вы предлагаете избавиться.  
если честно, я ваше предложение вообще не понял

Comment: @miramentis, Вы бы еще через полгода возобновили тему. Давайте я Вам просто в ответе код, который набросал 

    -rwxrwx--- 1 avp avp 1845 Oct 24 21:20 bigdec-bin.c*

кину?

А там, думаю, разберетесь.

Comment: @avp давайте, буду очень благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, решил я так:
Из второго тома Д.Кнута алгоритм(спасибо @VladD за то что указал где искать):
для числа, имеющего M+1>1 разрядов: [image]

```
    ENT1  M-1         j ← m-1
    LDA   INPUT+M     U ← u_m
2H  MUL   =10=
    SLAX  5
    ADD   INPUT,1     U ← 10U + u_j
    DEC1  1
    J1NN  2B          Повторять при m > j ≥ 0
```

и мой код на C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
//обрабатываем случай, когда у числа всего 1 десятичный разряд
char first = getc(stdin), second = getc(stdin);
ungetc(second,stdin); ungetc(first,stdin);
if(second=='\n')  ungetc('0',stdin);
//выделяем память "с запасом" под худший случай - 10^10000 десятичных знаков ~=32кб
bool* arr = (bool*)malloc(sizeof(bool)*34000);
bool* arr1;
int end = 0;
for(int i=0;i<34000;i++,arr[i]=false);
int a=(int)getc(stdin)-48;
//записываем самый старший разряд числа "как в школе учили" делением на 2
do{
    arr[end]=(bool)(a&1);
    a>>=1;
    end++;
}while(a);
a=(int)getc(stdin)-48;
//обрабатываем остальные разряды
while(a!=-38){
    //реализуем умножение текущего накопленного значения на 10:
    //x*10 = x*8 + x*2 == x<<3 + x<<1
    arr1 = (bool*)malloc(sizeof(bool)*(end+4));
    arr1[0]=false;
    //записываем число сдвинутое на 1
    memcpy(arr1+1,arr,end+3);
    //сдвигаем само число на 3
    memmove(arr+3,arr,end);
    arr[0]=false;arr[1]=false;arr[2]=false;
    end+=3;
    //суммируем выше полученные числа
    bool nextOverhead,overhead=false;
    for(int i=1;i<=end;i++){
        nextOverhead=((arr[i]&&arr1[i]) || (arr[i]&&overhead) || (arr1[i]&&overhead));
        arr[i]^=arr1[i]^=overhead;
        overhead=nextOverhead;
    }
    if(arr[end])end++;
    //прибавляем следующий разряд
    overhead=false;
    for(int i=0;a || nextOverhead;i++){
        nextOverhead=((arr[i] && ((bool)(a&1))) || 
                                  (arr[i] && overhead)    || 
                                (((bool)(a&1)) && overhead));
        arr[i]^=overhead^=((bool)(a&1));
        overhead=nextOverhead;
        a>>=1;
    }
    if(arr[end])end++;
    a=(int)getc(stdin)-48;
    free(arr1);
}
for(int i=end-1;i>=0;i--)
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: @miramentis, какие-то странные маипуляции у Вас с ungetc().

Если я правильно понял, Вы каждый бит (двоичный разряд) в храните в одном байте и работаете с ними?

Comment: так как указатель arr имеет тип bool, то и индексирование будет побитовое, а не побайтовое.  
34000 ячеек, так как при N=10^10000 нам потребуется  lb(10^10000)~=33220 (я округлил в коде)ячеек - худший случай.  
согласен, не рационально выделять под любые числа такой объем памяти, хотя с другой стороны это ~4кб оперативной памяти... при желании, полагаю, можно модифицировать для более рационального выделения памяти

Comment: @miramentis: мне кажется, не имеет смысла экономить память упаковкой битов, т. к. побитовое индексирование медленнее. Расход памяти в 4К вполне себе можно проигнорировать на современных машинах.

Comment: @VladD побитовое индексирование медленнее? если можно, объясните пожалуйста почему или дайте ссылку.  
то есть, если я возьму массив char и массив bool одинаковой длинны, то индексирование по первому будет быстрее?  
вы считаете, что лучше хранить каждый бит в одном байте? хотя, в этом случае памяти будет всего 32кб использовано, что весьма мало, все равно, это звучит странно...

Comment: @miramentis, чтобы много не говорить, смотрите

    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    int main(int ac, char *av[])
    {
      cout << "sizeof(bool): " << sizeof(bool) << '\n';
      bool arr[10000];
      cout << "sizeof(bool arr[10000]): " << sizeof(arr) << '\n';
    }
    
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ boolsize.cpp 
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    sizeof(bool): 1
    sizeof(bool arr[10000]): 10000
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 

Это по поводу размеров `bool` (естественно, размер в байтах).

--

А про `ungetc()`:

    only one pushback is guaranteed

Comment: @avp спасибо, что просветили... вот уж не думал, что так оно...  
но раз уж @VladD сказал, что не стоит заботиться об упаковке битов, это не существенно^^  
тем не менее, все же интересно:  
1) как все же упаковать биты?  
2) что можно использовать вместо ungetc?(или как можно изменить мою проверку на количество символов в потоке?)

Comment: Ваши действия с ungetc() как-то вводят в заблуждение. Вы бы просто словами описали формат своих данных.

Наверное для начала проще всего сделать  одну длинную строку десятичных цифр. И читать ее, пока цифра. Тогда никаких ungetc() вообще не нужно.

--

По поводу упаковки. Если Вы хотите манипулировать битами в массиве байт по индексу бита, то можно так

    #define CLRBIT(s,i) ({ int _i = (i); (s)[_i >> 3] &= ~(1 << (_i & 7)); })
    #define SETBIT(s,i) ({ int _i = (i); (s)[_i >> 3] |= (1 <<  (_i & 7)); })
    #define TSTBIT(s,i) ({ int _i = (i); (s)[_i >> 3] & (1 << (_i & 7)); })

Comment: @miramentis: По поводу сравнительной скорости работы с упакованными битами и распакованными: для упакованного бита получение его значения по индексу делается, как в макросе @avp в предыдущем комментарии:

    isset = data[i >> 3] & (1 << (i & 7));

С неупакованным представлением проще:

    isset = data[i];

Как вы думаете, что скорее работает?

Comment: @miramentis, а что, теперь все вроде нормально. Я бы тоже делал с распакованными (1 бит на байт). Только `malloc()` в цикле убрал. Просто завел бы 2 массива по максимуму и сделал функцию, суммирующую 3 числа.

Т.е. получилось бы что-то такое 

    char a1[N], a2[N], a[4], *res, *p_res;
    int n, curbits = 1;
    
    memset(a1, 0, sizeof(a1));
    memcpy(a2, a1, sizeof(a1));
    res = a1 + 3;
    p_res = a2 + 3;
    
    while ((n = getdbits(a, stdin)) > 0) {
        curbits = add3(res, p_res - 3, curbits + 3, p_res - 1, curbits + 1, a, n);
        memcpy(p_res, res, curbits);
    }
    
все

Comment: В одном комментарии не помещается.

--

Также убираем `memmove()`, "моделируем" сдвиг на 1 и 3, передавая адреса перед реальными битами числа, зная что фиктивные начальные биты это нули.

Думаю это несколько ускорит программу.

--

Ну, и чтобы не запутывать основную идею, напишем функцию, которая читает очередную десятичную цифру и возвращает массив ее бит и и их количество.

Она же возвращает, скажем ноль, когда закончатся десятичные цифры.

Остается распечатать `res` (в обратном порядке и скорректировав `curbits`, чтобы старший бит был 1).

Comment: @miramentis,
> так как указатель arr имеет тип bool, то и индексирование будет побитовое, а не побайтовое
В C++ sizeof(bool) >= 1, sizeof(char) == 1, т.е. bool занимает как минимум один байт.

Comment: Код в ответе точно переводит из десятичной записи в двоичную? Такое ощущение, что наоборот.



А насчёт битов, я слышал, что большинство процессоров с int'ами работают быстрее чем с char'ами ;) . Т.е. загрузка в регистр 4-х байт из памяти считается типичной операцией, а char'а - нет. И последняя решается по остаточному принципу путём чтения int'а и вырезания байта маской. Вроде в Core i7 поправили

Comment: @Михаил М точно, я проверял)
спасибо за информацию, попробую и так и так и посмотрю, как быстрее

Comment: @miramentis, действительно. Но, народ, вы что х№"%?* страдаете! Я себя чувствую superhackkiller'ом. А у него удар случится, если он увидит. Вроде серьёзные люди, обсуждаете, в каких ячейках (бит/байт/int) хранить биты. При этом обрабатываете биты по одному! Ну хотя бы по 28 бит в int'е храните и умножайте на 10 за проход. Тогда в 32 бита будет влезать. А если подумать, то лучше цифр по 9 за каждый проход добавлять

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, которые 10 триллионов знаков пи вычислили как-то сделали за O(n*log(n)^2). Можно скачать их исходники и попытаться понять, как. Или спросить. http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/#Algorithms

Возможно, они делят с остатком исходное число на 10^N, где N - такое, чтобы количество цифр в целом и остатке было одинаковым. А далее - рекурсивно для полученных половинок.

**Upd:** если вам не интересен алгоритм O(n*log(n)^2), пристойный алгоритм O(n^2) -

```
static const int bitsInCell = 28;
unsigned int data[32000 / bitsInCell + 10];
int i, dataLen = 1;
char ch;

memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    ch = getc(stdin);
    if (!isdigit(ch))
        break;
    data[0] = data[0] * 10 + ch - '0';
}

if (isdigit(ch))
    while (true)
    {
        ch = getc(stdin);
        if (!isdigit(ch))
            break;

        // Умножаем на 10
        data[0] = data[0] * 10 + ch - '0';

        for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i++)
        {
            unsigned int carryValue = data[i] / (1U << bitsInCell);

            data[i] %= 1U << bitsInCell;
            data[i + 1] = data[i + 1] * 10 + carryValue;
        }
        if (data[dataLen] > 0)
             dataLen++;
    }

// Вывод битов из data
```

Answer (score 0):

[@miramentis](/users/13348/miramentis), ловите.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
getdecbits (char arr[])
{
  int end = -1, a;

  if (isdigit(a = getchar())) {
    end = 0;
    a -= '0';
    do {
      arr[end++] = a & 1;
    } while ( a >>= 1 );
  }

  return end;
}

// вычисление y = x * 10 + d как  x >> 3 + x >> 1 + d
// складывает x3[], x1[] и d[] 
//  (двоичные, один бит в байте, старшие справа)
//  (в x3[] и x1[] д.б. досаточно старших нулевых бит)
// Returns длину результата >= max(l1, l2, l3)
int 
add3 (char res[], char x3[], int l1, 
       char x1[], int l2, char d[], int l3)
{
  int i, s = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < l3; i++) {
    s += x3[i] + x1[i] + d[i];
    res[i] = s & 1;
    s >>= 1;
  }
  for (; i < l2; i++) {
    s += x3[i] + x1[i];
    res[i] = s & 1;
    s >>= 1;
  }
  for (; i < l1 && s; i++) {
    s += x3[i];
    res[i] = s & 1;
    s >>= 1;
  }
  if (s)
    do {
      res[i++] = s & 1;
    } while ( s >>= 1 );
  else for (; i < l1; i++)
         res[i] = x3[i];

  return i;
}

int
correct_nbits (char a[], int l)
{
  while (l > 0 && !a[l])
    l--;
  return l + 1;
}

#define N (64 * 1024)

int 
main ()
{
  char array1[N], array2[N], a[4], *res, *prev_res;
  int nbits, curbits = 1;

  memset(array1, 0, sizeof(array1));
  memcpy(array2, array1, sizeof(array1));
  res = array1 + 3;
  prev_res = array2 + 3;
  while ((nbits = getdecbits(a)) > 0) {
    curbits = add3(res, prev_res - 3, curbits + 3, 
                      prev_res - 1, curbits + 1, a, nbits);
    memcpy(prev_res, res, curbits);
  }

  printf("Result: (%d bits)\n", curbits = correct_nbits(res, curbits));
  for (int i = curbits - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  //  for (int i = 0; i < curbits; i++)
    putchar(res[i] + '0');
  puts("");

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc -std=gnu99 bigdec-bin.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
15
Result: (4 bits)
1111
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
32
Result: (6 bits)
100000
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc -std=gnu99 bigdec-bin.c -O3
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./mkdigs 30
367535629127093606261879202375
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./mkdigs 3 | ./a.out
Result: (9 bits)
101101111
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ time ./mkdigs 10000 | ./a.out >/dev/null

real    0m0.288s
user    0m0.284s
sys     0m0.000s
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

В исходника размер массивов 64КБ, достаточно для преобразования

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ time ./mkdigs 19700 | ./a.out >/dev/null

real    0m0.890s
user    0m0.892s
sys     0m0.000s
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

примерно 19700 десятичных цифр. А вот исходника ./mkdigs не сохранилось, но он тривиален, на основе `rand() % 10`.

Comment: @miramentis, смотрите, какая идея пришла в голову. Можно вообще избавиться от копирования в while(...).

Достаточно установить res и prev_res не на начало массивов, а отступив 3/4 его размера и после каждой цифры сдвигать указатели на 3 к началу и обменивать их содержимое.

Т.е. получаемое двоичное число будет строиться одновременно влево и вправо (за счет битов переноса), в четных итерациях в array1[], а в нечетных в array2[].

--

Обдумайте, все должно получиться. (2 недели я не буду отвечать, отъезжаю).

Answer (score 0):

1. Перевести исходное число в систему счисления с основанием 10<sup>9</sup> (можно по Кнуту, можно через sscanf()). "Цифры" хранить в 32-битовом целом формате.
2. Перевести "уголком" полученное число в систему счисления с основанием 2<sup>32</sup>, при делении использовать расширенные умножения и сдвиги. Запись остатков-"цифр" в массив результата идёт в обратном порядке.
3. Перевести каждую новую "цифру" в 32-символьную двоичную строку, начиная с последней (например, через sprintf()). В последней строке убрать ведущие нули, в остальных - сохранить.