# Перевод в десятичную систему счисления больших двоичных чисел

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Никак не могу найти алгоритм, только обратный нашел [Перевод в двоичную систему счисления больших чисел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262945/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB#)

Comment: Переведите в BCD с помощью "дабл дабл", в нем на каждую деятичную цифру полбайта. потом уже раздвиньте до нужного представления. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble Обратите внимание, сдвиги там чаще чем прибавление, так что можно двигать небольшую часть исходного числа, вовремя подхватывая новые байты. Только при add 3 придется подумать как перенос делать (который то же можно было бы накапливать что бы не проводить его  постоянно по всему числу. С другой стороны перенос все равно на первом же 0 бите остановится

Comment: Алгоритм такой: делим число на 10 получаем остаток и целый результат. остаток деления (от '0' до '9') записываем вначало строки. Если целый результат деления больше 0, повторяем операцию.

Comment: @Mike: алгоритм похоже для чисел, которые в регистре помещаются (в железе реализовать). Для больших чисел возможно лучше ["разделяй и властвуй" sub-quadratic  подход из GMP использовать](https://gmplib.org/manual/Binary-to-Radix.html)

Answer (score 1):

Требуемый алгоритм несложен.
Для перевода числа в другую систему счисления достаточно многократного деления с остатком на основание новой системы счисления, при котором частное используется в качестве нового делителя. Запись числа в новой системе счисления - это последовательность остатков, записанная в обратном порядке.

С практической точки зрения, делить длинное число на 10 - не лучший вариант. Лучше использовать промежуточную систему счисления (например, по основанию 1 000 000 или 1 000 000 000), что сокращает количество "длинных" делений.

Comment: это звучит как квадратичный алгоритм. Если число "большое", то цифр может быть много и можно [долго ждать результата для `O(n**2)` алгоритма](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28480239/4279). Можно посмотреть, [что GMP использует для получения десятичных цифр](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/generic/get_str.c)

Comment: @jfs Пока неясно, о каком диапазоне больших числел речь, вопрос повисает в воздухе

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм приходит легко, если понимать запись двоичного числа.
Например, рассмотрим двоичное число ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В десятичной форме оно будет выглядеть так:

dec_num = 2^0 + 2^5 + 2^7 = 161

То есть мы просто сложили двойки в степенях позиций с ненулевыми значениями.
Как же нам это закодить?

На каждой итерации нашего алгоритма мы должны знать:

1)позицию элемента(в общем-то это есть значение нашего счётчика цикла)

2)цифру числа в данной позиции

Чтобы узнать последнюю цифру числа достаточно взять остаток от деления по модулю 10(операция bin_num%10). Но как тогда узнать предпоследнюю? Очень просто! Достаточно модифицировать наше бинарное число в конце каждой итерации следующим образом
bin_num/=10. Применяя эту операцию, мы как бы сдвигаем число вправо, делая его предпоследнюю цифру последней, чтобы операция bin_num%10 давала нужный результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь этих рассуждений достаточно, чтобы найти верное решение:)